# Powershell - Import local CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I have a powershell script that imports a CSV file using this command:

```
$empCsv = Import-Csv "addEmp.csv"
```

I have the csv sitting in the same directory as the script but I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException`. If I use the command with a path to the CSV like this:

```
$empCsv = Import-Csv .\Desktop\createUser\addEmp.csv
```

It works fine.

I want to be able to give this script to someone to use and let them run the script from any location and be able to import the `.csv` that's sitting in the same directory.

Why can't my first command find the csv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To import a CSV in the same directory, I suggest:

```
$empCsv = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\addEmp.csv"
```

`PSScriptRoot` gives you the path of the currently executing script.

Comment: Quick and easy.

Thank you!