# Using PSScriptRoot with Import-CSV

Tags: powershell, import-csv

As detailed in:

[PowerShell-Import-Local-CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326806/powershell-import-local-csv)

```
$empCsv = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\addEmp.csv"
```

Is classed as an answer. This doesn't work for me when i run this code inside a function. How can i test this?

Answer (score 0):

You can test your Powershell version with `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`.
If it is below version 3.0 you can use:

```
Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
```

to find the directory the current script is running from instead of `$PSScriptRoot`.

Comment: I'm having a problem importing the CSV using my import-csv $PSScriptRoot Folder\file.csv. It doesn't work.

Comment: Aha, but then please explain *what* exactly does not work. Do you get error messages?

Answer (score 0):

[`$PSScriptRoot` will provide the path for the currently running script/function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#psscriptroot), so if a script runs a function from another location, `$PSScriptRoot` will contain that other location.

If you want to get the path of the script that's calling the function, leverage `$MyInvocation`:

```
$empCsv = Import-Csv "$(Split-Path $MyInvocation.ScriptName)\addEmp.csv"
```

---

**Demo**

- Create the `Test.psm1` file.
- Create the `Caller.ps1` file in a subfolder.
- Run `Caller.ps1`.
- `$PSScriptRoot` will refer to `Test.psm1` location, `$MyInvocation` will refer to `Caller.ps1` location.

`Test.psm1`:

```
Function Test{
    Write-host "PSScriptRoot: $PSScriptRoot"
    Write-host "MyInvocation: $(Split-Path $MyInvocation.ScriptName)"
}
```

`Caller.ps1`:

```
Import-Module ..\Test.psm1 -Force
Test
```